# Load ListBox with folder contents through MFDialogboxFolder

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to load a listbox with files in a folder through MFDialogbox Picker.

Unfortunately, its not working. Request your help.

Below is the code, I am using. Thanks

I find that 'mypath' variable is holding the correct name of the folder that was selected.

But, I find nothing is working thereafter. Please help.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim myfiles As String, mypath As String
Dim fileList() As String
    Dim fName As String
    Dim fPath As String
    Dim I As Integer

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show = False Then Exit Sub
    mypath = .SelectedItems(1)
    DoEvents
End With

MsgBox mypath

If Right(mypath, 1) <> "\" Then mypath = mypath & "\"
ReDim fileList(1 To I)

fName = Dir(mypath)
MsgBox fName
    While fName <> ""
         'add fName to the list
        I = I + 1
        ReDim Preserve fileList(1 To I)
        fileList(I) = fName
         'get next filename
        fName = Dir()
    Wend
     'see if any files were found
    If I = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No files found"
        Exit Sub
    End If
     'cycle through the list and add to listbox
    For I = 1 To UBound(fileList)
        Me.ListBox1.AddItem fileList(I)
    Next


End Sub
```

Comment: remove ReDim fileList(1 To I).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that I is 0 (as it is not set) when reaching `ReDim fileList(1 To I)`. If you replace it with `ReDim fileList(1 To 1)`, it should work.